# ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index with Transformer

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

For code below

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer
from functools import partial
from types import FunctionType
from statistics import mean

import pandas as pd

X_train = pd.DataFrame(columns=['domain'])

# Add rows to the dataframe
X_train.loc[36] = ['e1548bfed8d05713acacc4d33393b258.org']
X_train.loc[25] = ['google.de']

# Print the resulting dataframe
print(X_train)

def wrapper(series: pd.Series, func: FunctionType) -> pd.DataFrame:
    return pd.DataFrame(series.apply(func))

class CustomFunctionTransformer(FunctionTransformer):
    def __init__(self, func):
        super().__init__(partial(wrapper, func=func), validate=False)
        pass


    
class AverageDigitDistanceTransformer(CustomFunctionTransformer):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(average_digit_distance)
        
def average_digit_distance(string: str) -> float:
    digit_indices = [i for (i,c) in enumerate(string) if c.isdigit()]
    digit_distances = [succ - pred for pred, succ in zip(digit_indices, digit_indices[1:])]
    return mean(digit_distances) if digit_distances else 0.0

#error is from below line
X_train[['domain']].apply(AverageDigitDistanceTransformer().transform)
```

I have exception:

> ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

How should I solve it?